Is there any way I can trigger a Jenkins pipeline based on an outlook 365 email
I am trying to investigate an option to trigger a Jenkins pipeline when an email with certain subject is received in a outlook 365 mailbox/email account. Is there any way to achieve same.
I cant see any proper documentation regarding this by doing a google search. Any pointers will be appreciated
